# css grids - do I still need to use lists?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, semantic-markup

I'm sorry, this isn't really a code issue specifically other than I'm looking for simplification.

I'm trying to migrate to using CSS grids since the concept seems great and a lot more intuitive - but before I get carried away I'm just considering one point to experiment with.

**Does css grids render lists useless?**

Instead of:

```
<ul class="floater-left">
    <li>x</li>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>z</li>
</ul>
```

do I now just need:

```
<div class="grid-type-1">  // where this type 1 has set out columns
    <p>x</p>
    <p>y</p>
    <p>z</p>
</div>
```

Because now I can order my "list" by dropping in some selectors, make it easier to spread the list out, justify etc.

Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** You still need lists (if you need a list in your document).

**Long answer:** Markup semantics trump `CSS` conveniences. If it makes semantic sense to present a given `HTML` structure using a `ul`, then use one. Although developers may not see the difference using a `p` or `li`, screen readers will present our possibly misguided `HTML` to individuals with various challenges (visual, tactile, etc.) who greatly depend on the accuracy of an `HTML` document.

Comment: Ah, great point about parsing for <li> elements etc. now that has made me think twice about taking the plunge. Using just <p> simplifies my css by a few lines but may not be worth it further down the line...

Answer (score 1):

[**li**] tag and [**Div**] tag is same in showing
But in the concept of structure, it has difference
Using [**li**] tag is better expression in List items.